# Using SCSS in svelte & vite - "Colon is expected"

Tags: css, sass, svelte, vite

I recently installed svelte & vite in order to learn the platform, but I can't seem to get any SCSS to compile. Svelte is running just fine, and if I change the SCSS to plain CSS then it works (so svelte and vite appear to running just fine).

I've run the following commands:

> npm install svelte-preprocess sass --save-dev
> npm i --save-dev sass
> npm install svelte-preprocess scss --save-dev
> npm i --save-dev scss

My `vite.config.js` looks like this (yes, both mixins.scss and variables.scss exist at those locations, though I'm not yet using anything from those files)...

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte({
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess()
  })],
  css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {                                 
              additionalData: `
              @use './src/lib/scss/mixins' as *;
              @use './src/lib/scss/variables' as *;
          `,
          }
      }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve("/src"),
    },
  }
});
```

And `svelte.config.js` looks like...

```js
export default {
  preprocess: vitePreprocess()
}
```

Then I have a component, `Header.svelte` which contains...

```html
<style type="text/scss">
    header {
      h1 {
        color: red;
      }
    }
</style>

<header>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</header>
```

This is where the error occurs...

[image]

What might I have missed?

Comment: “This is where the error occurs.” — Where exactly? What is the *complete* error message? Does it mention a file name, line number, and line position? Is it a JS error, a SASS error, or something else?

Comment: @Quentin - I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/preprocess.md#vitepreprocess) the tag is wrong. It should be:

```html
<style lang="scss">
```

Also, you maybe should not be using both processors (the one from `@sveltejs/kit/vite` and `svelte-preprocess`) at the same time. One should be enough, the latter should have more features as far as I know.
Would only set a preprocessor in `svelte.config.js`, not the `vite.config.js`.